# RedBean One to Many Attribute Not Working

Tags: php, model-view-controller, orm, redbean

Edit: rewriting my question

I have a one-many relation that sets files to a publication. It doesn't work as I expected, when I do:

```
var_dump($this->pub->xownFiles);
R::store($this->pub);
var_dump($this->pub->xownFiles);
```

The first var_dump gives me:

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean)#37 (10) { ["properties":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(9) "Koala.jpg" ["size"]=> int(780831) ... (etc.)
```

But the second var_dump, after storing it gives:

`array(0) { }`

Why is this? Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, I've been debugging for ages and I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, Redbean sure has some non-intuitive syntax sometimes.

`$this->pub->xownFile` is the correct call, i.e. removing the plural...